# Can I deactivate / reactivate Google AdSense at any time?

Tags: google-adsense, blogger, visitors, advertising

I have a blog on **Blogger** which is not very popular (and it does not even have a second-level domain). In any case I would like to subscribe to Google **AdSense** and try this service to see how it does work, because I have some other few projects for the future and I would like to become more expert on that.
Therefore I want to do a sort of experiment, as it were, and see how much invasive banner ads are, how they work, learn how to monitor my performances and so on... and then possibly **deactivate** it and come back to the previous plan. So

- *Once I activated Google **AdSense** and let it put **banner ads** on my blog, can I **unsubscribe at any time**, **without being penalized**, if I change my mind and **I no longer want to show advertising**, even temporarily (I mean: is the operation totally reversible?)?*

Comment: Yes, Ofcourse you can deactivate your adsense account at any time, but for [reactive?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/sLELVjBtvvU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only site has a blogspot.com domain, not a custom domain, then your experience of AdSense is different - as described here:   http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2016/02/with-only-blogger-blog-do-not-apply-to.html

To follow your plan, I would strongly suggest getting a custom domain and going thru the standard AdSense sign-up process.   If you do that, you can add/remove your advertising units from any site which complies with their policies.

No need to un-subscribe or de-activate, just choose not to show ads at certain times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the ad code from your source and it won't display it, 
but that doesn't mean you can deactivate your account and activate it again, at least that's what I think since I already don't have access to the UI of adsence, but I'm certain that you can remove the embed of the ad and it would be a no prob for adsence.

In my experience with AdSence I got banned for multiple clicks from an IP address, and the IP they listed wasn't even mine, so I'm not really sure if you can get banned because somebody else is making fake clicks on your ads, but I guess something went wrong back there, because I've seen many people happily running adsence.